# Need to display data in format January 2020, February 2019,... using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created month name column using **monthname(date)** to get **January** but i need to get data as **January 2020** i.e. i need to get monthname and year as well. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *could* use:

```
select concat(monthname(date), ' ', year(date))
```

More commonly, you would use [`date_format()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html):

```
select date_format(date, '%M %Y')
```